# I'm new to python and pynag and I keep getting a syntax error when trying to put a pynag command into my python script

Tags: python

I'm trying to put in a pynag command in my python script and I keep getting this syntax error:

```
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `pynag add hostgroup hostgroup_name={0}.format(hostgroup_name) --filename=/etc/nagios/objects/{0}.format(id)/{0}.format(id)_{0}.cfg.format(hostgroup_name))'
```

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import sys
import subprocess
import csv
import getopt
import time
import datetime
import logging
from sys import argv
script, solution_id, input_file = argv
from pynag import Model


def main():
#creating time stamp and returning as a string to add to solution id log name  
    def timeIzNow():  
        full = time.strftime(" %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

        return full

    #set up logging file
    LOG_FILENAME = solution_id  + timeIzNow() 
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s %(process)d',
                    datefmt='%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S', 
                    filename=LOG_FILENAME,
              filemode='w')   
    #defining a Handler which writes INFO messages or higher to the sys.stderr
    console = logging.StreamHandler()
    console.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    #setting a format which is simpler for console use
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
    #telling the handler to use this format
    console.setFormatter(formatter)
    #adding the handler to the root logger
    logging.getLogger('').addHandler(console)

    current_file = csv.reader(open(input_file, "rb"), delimiter='\t')
    for line in current_file:
        for column in current_file:  
            hostgroup_name = column[4]
            id = column[2]   

    hg = os.system('pynag add hostgroup hostgroup_name={0}.format(hostgroup_name) --filename=/etc/nagios/objects/{0}.format(id)/{0}.format(id)_{0}.cfg.format(hostgroup_name))')

    hostgroup = os.system('pynag list hostgroup_name WHERE object_type=hostgroup')
    if not hostgroup:
        logging.error("Hostgroup %s not found." % hostgroup_name)
        #print 'adding objects'
    else:
        return hg

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a string which has format placed in it, so this gets sent along verbatim when you make the system call. This is sending the string `'pynag add hostgroup hostgroup_name={0}.format(hostgroup_name) --filename=/etc/nagios/objects/{0}.format(id)/{0}.format(id)_{0}.cfg.format(hostgroup_name))'` to the shell which is not what you want. To fix this you need to change how you are using `format` by taking it out of the string:

```
hg = os.system('pynag add hostgroup hostgroup_name={0} --filename=/etc/nagios/objects/{1}/{1}_{0})'.format(hostgroup_name,id))
```

or alternatively if you use names it looks like this:

```
hg = os.system('pynag add hostgroup hostgroup_name={hg} --filename=/etc/nagios/objects/{id}/{id}_{hg})'.format(hg=hostgroup_name, id=id))
```

There are some good examples of how this works over on the [python string documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/string.html#format-examples).

Comment: Thanks. It's pulling the right info now but I still get this syntax error sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
sh: -c: line 0: `pynag add hostgroup hostgroup_name=ISD-CR-All_Servers --filename=/etc/nagios/objects/ISD-CR/ISD-CR_ISD-CR-All_Servers).cfg'

Comment: Okay I found the error. There was an extra closing bracket. It works now. Thanks.